# What does the id of the name of the list specify in python?

Tags: python, list

I had written a code to print the `id` of the name and the elements of the `list`:

```
sample_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(f"The id of the name of the list is = {id(sample_list)}")
for i in range(0, len(sample_list)):
    print(f"Id of element index {i} is {id(sample_list[i])}")
```

Output:

```
The id of the name of the list is = 2874211984576
Id of element index 0 is 2874206087472
Id of element index 1 is 2874206087504
Id of element index 2 is 2874206087536
Id of element index 3 is 2874206087568
Id of element index 4 is 2874206087600
```

I want to know why does the `id` of the `list` name is not same as the first element of the `list` as it was in `C` with `arrays`?

If not please tell me what does the `id`/`address` of the name of the list specify and how the members of the `list` is stored in the memory blocks? I recently switched to `python` from `C`.

Comment: Unlike C, in python `list` objects & the things that they contain are allocated independently. The objects that are in the list can be located anywhere in memory (not necessarily contiguous). The list object itself has some memory associated with it - that also might be anywhere in memory (not constrained by where the contents are being stored). The list itself has _references_ to the objects it is supposed to store. In C, this would be like an array of pointers (gross oversimplification).

Comment: Also of note, the `id()` function is supposed to return only "a unique identifier for the object". - the fact that it returns the memory location is a CPython implementation detail & not a part of the python language spec.

Comment: The `id` is assigned to the object when it is created. The `id` is the object's memory address, and will be different for each time you run the program. (except for some object that has a constant unique id, like integers from -5 to 256)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:** python `list`'s are not arrays of values. They are arrays of pointers that point to values.

The exact value of `id` is an implementation detail of the cpython interpreter (the implementation of python developed by the python software foundation). According to the definition of the language it is only guaranteed to uniquely identify objects.

regarding cpython:

In python all objects (anything you can assign to a variable is an object) are stored in heap as a struct containing some information about reference counting, type, value, etc... The `id` function happens to be implemented as the value of the pointer to that struct. A python `list` has this same struct, and the "value" ends up being an array of pointers to other PyObject structs. These pointers have no relation to the location of the array of pointers (reference counting is another discussion), so there is no expectation for them to be in any order. Even something as simple as an integer must have one of these PyObject structs.