# Why id() returns same for different objects

Tags: python, list, memory

```
def add_item(list_x=[]):

    list_x = list_x + [3]

    print(list_x)

    print(id(list_x))

add_item() 

add_item([1,2])

add_item()

add_item([5,6])

add_item()
```

I expected first function call list and third function call should give same id but second and third are giving same ids and similary fourth and fifth giving same

here is the output:

```
[3]
140010993189184
[1, 2, 3]
140010993171520
[3]
140010993171520
[5, 6, 3]
140010993159232
[3]
140010993159232
```

Comment: I'm not sure the marked duplicate is all that relevant here. The line `list_x = list_x + [3]` locally rebinds the name `list_x`, without mutating anything. So the default argument (while it is a mutable object) is never in fact mutated.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id As it quotes from the Python docs: **"Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value."**

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449489/when-are-objects-garbage-collected-in-python?rq=3

Comment: @deceze In what way is the "mutable default" duplicate relevant here?

Comment: @Kelly It doesn’t hurt having it there, does it? This code is suspiciously close to developing a problem with it.

Comment: @deceze If it has nothing to do with the issue, then I find it distracting/misleading.

Comment: @deceze When you come to this page, the "least astonishment" question appears in the list "This question already has answers here". That's what's problematic IMO - nothing in the "least astonishment" question answers OP's question here.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380984/21127400)

This is probably because python doesn't keep unnecessary (unobsolete) data in memory, I don't know exactly python's memory management code, but all software languages do this, and the id method already gives its position in memory.

First call generates a list on memory that has one elements, prints it and interpreter removes list from memory, second one generates 3 elements, but second list it is bigger, so cannot stored in last space, interpreter puts this another space in memory, code prints and interpreter removes from memory, third one is smaller, so interpreter puts it in last space, etc.

Comment: Right, as soon as the `add_item` function completes, the `list_x` that it created (note, not the default argument of the function) has zero reference count. So (at least in CPython) it gets garbage collected, and there is nothing to prevent its memory address being reused by another object.